# Open infinite games and payoff functions

Tags: game-theory

Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and $d(A,B)=\sum_{n\in A\Delta B}2^{-n}$, where $A\Delta B = (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$, be a metric on subsets of the natural numbers. I'm asked to show that for [Gale-Stewart games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem#Gale.E2.80.93Stewart_games) there does not exists a continuous function which decides the winner (when $d$ is used on subsets of $\mathbb{N}$). I've been hinted that, under $d$, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} G_n=\emptyset$, where $G_n$ is the positions after $2n$ moves which guarantees player $I$ to win (which i suppose is contradictory and somehow this should lead to the conclusion that a continuous function deciding the winner does not exist).

Don't know where to start. Help.

Comment: In Gale-Stewart games, you can typically draw elements *with replacement.*  Here, it would seem that your distance function can't handle multi-sets.  What's going on?

Comment: @AWalker: I really don't know exactly what I've been asked to prove here, or how, to be honest. This was given as an extra task at the end of a project mainly consideringen determinacy of Gale-Stewart games, so I'm really not sure how the given distance function/metric plays in when it comes to payoff functions. I think the lack of continuity has something to do with the payoff set beeing open, and thus a function can't "travel" continuously through the whole set of plays, when this metric is applied, somehow (but I'm really not sure about anything here).

Comment: This is just me spit-balling, but suppose that $f: \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \{0,1\}$ (the set of outcomes) is continuous.

Let's assume by symmetry that $f^{-1}(0) \neq \varnothing$.  If $X \in f^{-1}(0)$, then by continuity we can find an open neighborhood $U$ at $X$ such that $f(U) = \{0\}$, because $\{0\}$ is open in the set of outcomes.

With respect to the topology on $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$, there exists some integer $N > 0$ such that if $Y$ and $X$ differ by elements greater than $N$, we must have $f(Y)=\{0\}$.

In particular, the game is then determined by finitely many moves?